# Is Sql Compact Edition database still readable after password protection and encryption?

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-ce

Out of [this page by Microsoft about Sql Compact Edition database encryption](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171741(v=sql.110).aspx)

> The password does not prevent the reading of any data in the database file as clear text. By using both encryption and a password, you can store the data in an encrypted format and restrict programmatic access to the database.

so, just to get it clear.. after password protection and encryption of the database, the data might be still readable in some ways? and the only thing blocked is the programmatic data connection?

so if someone has this encrypted and password protected database, he/she could read the data in it? what is the sense in that?

Someone please clear this up to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MSDN article states, that just password protection is not sufficient to prevent someone from opening the database file in e.g. a text editor and recovering the stored plaintext.
If the database is encrypted (and therefore also password protected), its contents should not be recoverable without providing the password (i.e. opening the database file will show only 'scrambled' text).

Comment: I had the feeliing and the hope that this would be the answer but for some reason my logic said otherwise.. I thought that `you can store the data in an encrypted format and restrict programmatic access to the database.` meant that you could still read the data in some way but just not to connect to the database in a programmatic way. sorry for the confusion and thank you! thanks for changing the tags for me though it looks I'm just asked the first and only question with the "sqlce" tag.. interesting.. is it so unpopular?